# Set user_id in Mlflow

Tags: python, mlflow

I am running MLflow with several users can instanciate experiments.

Is there any way to override user_id which is set to system username?

Looking for a solution which works with start_run block.

Any ideas?

```py
with mlflow.start_run():
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the user_id by setting it as an environment variable;

```
os.environ["LOGNAME"] = "my_user_id"
```

MLflow will automatically use the defined environment variable LOGNAME as the user_id in the experiment tag.

Answer (score 0):

`start_run` doesn't support `user_id` as argument, and its kwargs are actually Run tags, so you need to work with other functions.

In order to do what you need, you have to create for yourself the run from a `FileStore` object, then wrap this new `run` inside an `ActiveRun` wrapper, that after the with-block will automatically finish the run passed as argument.

The code should look like this.

```py
import time

import mlflow
from mlflow import ActiveRun
from mlflow.store.tracking.file_store import FileStore

now = int(time.time() * 1000)  # mlflow default when start_time is None

fs = FileStore()
run = fs.create_run(
   experiment_id = None, # defaults to "0"
   user_id = "your_user_id", # your actual user-id
   start_time = now, 
   tags = {},
)

with ActiveRun(run) as arun:
   ...

# after with block, run is finished
```

Comment: Thanks. I ddn't get that to work. Hacked it with:

```python
os.environ["LOGNAME"] = "username"
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `LOGNAME` environment variable!  This works and seems to be the simplest  solution!